# url path variable in angular

Tags: angular, angular-routerlink

How get variable from url path variable in angular2(v12)

```
 path: 'shop/:id', <-- get id from here
 component: RedirectGuard,
  canActivate: [RedirectGuard],
  data: {
    externalUrl: `https://example.com/shop/:id` <-- set id to here
  }
```

Comment: Set it when you trigger navigation to the component, or use the params property and construct the required structure on the loaded component!

Comment: It's slow sometimes, because I want this method to redirect

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the [ActivateRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute) class in your component:

```
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

export class RedirectGuard implements OnInit {
 constructor(
        private route: ActivatedRoute
    ) {}

 ngOnInit() {
   const id = this.route.snapshot.params.id;
   this.router.navigate([`shop`, id]);
 }
}
```